# cannot connect asp.net application to POSTGRESQL database using npgsql data provider

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4, npgsql

I am new to asp.net MVC with C# and am using POSTGRESQL for database. I have a problem connecting to the POSTGRESQL on localhost from asp.net application using Npgsql. I get the following error

`The Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.`

My code in web.config file is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost; port=5432 ;user-id=postgres ;password=postgres ;database=postgres " providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

**NOTE:** I am using VS 2012 ,postgreSQL 9.6(pgadmin3) and have installed Entity framework version 6.0.0 package

Comment: Did you installed entityframework provider for npgsql? here is the link,https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/

Comment: Ohh, yes that was the issue. Thanks.